# How to stop evaluating lisp form when passed as function parameter?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am learning Lisp. Now I am trying to create a function that takes some valid Lisp form as argument and returns a function that executes the Lisp forms when called. For example:

```
(defun fn (name action)
  (setf (symbol-function name)
        #'(lambda () action)))
```

When I am passing say `(+ 4 5 6)` the function is getting created with specific name and when called returning the sum.

```
(fn 'add (+ 4 5 6))
(add) ==> 15
```

But if I invoke `(fn 'error (assert (= 2 3))` it is throwing error `(= 2 3) must evaluate to a non-NIL value.` and the function with name `error` is not created.

How can I stop this evaluation of `assert` when passed as function parameter?

Comment: Note that `error` is a Common Lisp function, you shouldn't redefine it.

Comment: @PauloMadeira Its just an example code to understand and experiment with the concepts.

Comment: I know, but I felt this comment was necessary, at least for posterity.  If you redefine `error`, even if just to experiment, you should expect the rest of your interaction with your Common Lisp implementation to be very unstable, to say the least.  You'd better experiment with symbols that don't name CL functions.  Unless you're curious about what may happen, which may be a didactic exploration.

Comment: Thanks @PauloMadeira I got your point.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot write this function; it has to be a macro operator. If `fn` is a function, then the call:

```
(fn 'add (+ 4 5 6))
```

evaluates the argument `(+ 4 5 6)`, reducing it to the value 15. The function receives 15, and not the expression. We can "fix" this by quoting the code:

```
(fn 'add '(+ 4 5 6))
```

but then we have the problem that the code doesn't interact with the lexical environment. For instance, this won't work, because `x` is not visible inside `fn`:

```
(let ((x 40)) (fn 'add '(+ x 2)))
```

To create a function which evaluates (+ x 2) in the proper environment, we must the `lambda` operator right in that same lexical scope:

```
(let ((x 40)) (lambda () (+ x 2)))
```

Your `fn` operator can be written as a syntactic sugar that generates the `lambda` (without any name):

```
(defmacro fn (expr) `(lambda () ,expr))
```

Now we can write:

```
(let ((x 40)) (fn (+ x 2))) ;; returns a function which returns 42
```

To do the named thing:

```
(defmacro fn (name expr) `(setf (symbol-function ',name) (lambda () ,expr)))
```

However, this is a quite a poor idea; we're introducing a nasty global side effect into a function. A better "named fn" might be one which introduces a lexical binding for a function over some forms. That is, it can be used like this:

```
(fn (foo (+ x 2)) (foo))
             ;;  ^^^^^^  foo is a lexical function in this scope
             ;;          denoting the function (lambda () (+ x 2))
```

That could be done like this:

```
(defmacro fn ((name expr) &rest forms)
   `(flet ((,name () ,expr)) ,@forms)))
```

Or, if you want the name as a variable binding rather than a function binding, so that the usage is  `(fn (foo (+ x 2)) (funcall foo)):`

```
(defmacro fn ((name expr) &rest forms)
  `(let ((,name (lambda () ,expr))) ,@forms))
```

Comment: Thanks Kaz for your input. I have one more query now: What is "lexical function" and in which scenario I may need them?

Comment: @Santanu Lexical (or "local") functions are introduced by `flet` and `labels` (the difference being that `labels` lets the defined function bodies "see" themselves and each other, allowing for self and mutual recursion). Lexical functions are useful when you want to decompose a function's task into smaller functions, but those functions need to have access to the local variables in the parent function.

Comment: Just a thought - can this lexical scoping in Lisp be used for implementing tighter encapsulation, for example something similar to `static` scope in C?

Comment: @Santanu, C does not have closures, so `static` specifier in C is just a replacement for them. With closures you can do more interesting things than with `static` specifier, and in more natural way.

Comment: @Mark But in C functions themselves can be used as variables by means of function pointers. Isn't it an equivalent concept to closures? We can pass function pointers as arguments to a function or we can have one as a return type of a function.

Comment: @Santanu No; closures consist of a function plus an environment. The function contains references to variables, which are satisfied by the environment. (Those which are not are "free variables"). A pointer to code is not a closure.  All functions in Common Lisp are closures; for instance `defun` works in terms of a closure, and therefore will capture an environment if it is enclosed in a `let`.

Comment: @Kaz Can I put `defclass` within a `let`? If so then I think very efficient builder pattern and DI can be coded in CL. Also if `defun` can be put inside `let` why do we have `flet` and `labels` in CL? I have seen the other day that in `On Lisp` they have used `defun` inside `let` and it appeared to me as surprise.

Comment: @Santanu, this row of comments gets too long, if you're interested in a dialog about closures and `let` over `defun`, we have [chat room dedicated to Lisp](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55226/lisp).

Answer (score 5):

Create the function, compile it and store it under `name`:

```
(defun fn (name action)
  (compile name
           `(lambda () ,action)))
```

Let's try it:

```
CL-USER 13 > (fn 'add '(+ 4 5 6))
ADD
NIL
NIL

CL-USER 14 > (add)
15
```

Comment: +1 I always forget that `compile` will set the definition of `name`. This is a very nice and clean solution.

Comment: This solution is something really very new to me. On searching net I get `(setf (symbol-function name) ...` always. So a query in my mind: what is the difference between `(setf (symbol-function name) ...` and `(compile name ...`? And when to use which?

Comment: @Santanu: this creates the function, compiles it and stores it. `setf symbol-function` just stores it.

Comment: @RainerJoswig: OK, so I can assume that compile gives performance improvement in executing the function over `setf symbol-function`.

Comment: Just now I found this in `On Lisp` and thought should mention it over here. `However, calling compile explicitly is a drastic measure, comparable to calling eval, and should be viewed with the same suspicion. ... Calling compile is not a routinely used programming technique-it's an extremely rare one. So beware of doing it unnecessarily.` Ref: [2.9 Compilation](http://dunsmor.com/lisp/onlisp/onlisp_6.html#SEC24)

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> (defun fn (name action) (setf (symbol-function name) #'(lambda () action)))
>
> (fn 'add (+ 4 5 6)) (add) ==> 15
> ```

This doesn't treat `add` and `(+ 4 5 6)` in the same way. You quote one (because you want a symbol), but not the other, even though you want a list.  To get the behavior you want, you'll either need to define a macro so that you can prevent evaluation and put the form inside a function, or to construct a list that you coerce to a function.  The macro approach:

```
(defmacro make-fn (name form)
  `(setf (symbol-function ',name) #'(lambda () ,form)))
```

```
CL-USER> (make-fn add (+ 4 5 6))
#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA ()) {1002D48D09}>
CL-USER> (add)
15
CL-USER> (make-fn err (assert (= 2 3)))
#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA ()) {1002E11359}>
CL-USER> (err)
; Evaluation aborted on #<SIMPLE-ERROR "The assertion ~S failed." {1002E24951}>.
```

The function and coerce approach:

```
(defun make-fn2 (name form)
  (setf (symbol-function name) (coerce (list 'lambda () form) 'function)))
```

```
CL-USER> (make-fn2 'add '(+ 4 5 6))
#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA ()) {1004566CB9}>
CL-USER> (add)
15
CL-USER> (make-fn2 'err '(assert (= 2 3)))
#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA ()) {100298D2F9}>
CL-USER> (err)
; Evaluation aborted on #<SIMPLE-ERROR "The assertion ~S failed." {10029CF441}>.
```

Now, these approaches will work fine, but [Rainer Joswig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24419379/1281433) points out that there's a standard function that already does most of this work for us: [compile](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cmp.htm).  It's pretty versatile, but the important parts are that it takes a name and optionally a function definition.  The function definition can be a lambda expression, and it will be coerced to a function (as above), but also compiled (since the simple coercion above might not compile the function) and store it as the function definition of the name, if name is non-nil.  That means that compile will do all the work of

```
(setf (symbol-function name) (coerce (list 'lambda () form) 'function))
```

for you, with the added benefit of compiling the function, too.  Rainer's answer shows how it can be used, and I think it's the most elegant solution to this problem.