# Syntax sugar for funcall?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp

Why there is no syntax sugar for funcall? We need it a lot. Won't it be great to write something like `(&#do-something arg0 arg1 arg2)` instead of `(funcall do-something arg0 arg1 arg2)` Why not add something like Ruby's &:method notation? Is there something already in the language?

Answer (score 9):

There's nothing like that built into the language;  you can easily assign the function to an additional name though, and use that.  E.g., if you want to use `&`, you can:

```
CL-USER> (setf (symbol-function '&) (symbol-function 'funcall))
#<FUNCTION FUNCALL>
CL-USER> (&'list 1 2 3)
(1 2 3)
CL-USER> (&'cons 'x 'y)
(X . Y)
```

(There was a recent question on Stack Overflow about different ways to do that first line: [How to stop evaluating lisp form when passed as function parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24418838/1281433).)

> Won't it be great to write something like `(&#do-something arg0 arg1 arg2)` instead of `(funcall do-something arg0 arg1 arg2)`?

Probably not.  Common Lisp is a language that prefers expressive names for functions and macros.  The name funcall is recognized, and it makes it clear that there's an indirect function call happening.  Why would we want to obscure that? Evidently most people find funcall has the right balance between "short enough to write" and "long enough to be descriptive".

> Why there is no syntax sugar for funcall?

You might call macros "syntax sugar" in Common Lisp, but there's no need for it here.  Funcall is a function, not a special form or macro, so it's really *very* easy to alias it with another name, as shown above.  The fact that most people *don't* do this should say something about how desirable it is.

Answer (score 8):

There is no syntax for `funcall`, because *we* don't need it a lot (or else, define "we").  I mean, in a Lisp-2, such as Common Lisp, that's the trade-off, and unless you're doing some heavy lambda calculus, you get used to it.

If you really want to use a more succint syntax, you can define a [dispatch macro character](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dh.htm):

```
(set-dispatch-macro-character
 #\# #\&
 #'(lambda (stream subchar arg)
     (let ((args-var (gensym)))
       `(lambda (&rest ,args-var)
          (declare (dynamic-extent ,args-var))
          (apply ,(read stream t nil t) ,args-var)))))

(let ((my-function #'max))
  (#&my-function 1 3 2))
```

Check if your compiler will optimize [lambda forms](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababd.htm) and [`dynamic-extent`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/d_dynami.htm) `&rest` arguments passed to [`apply`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_apply.htm).

I advise against defining the single character `&` as a [macro character](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_set_ma.htm), because it's a [constituent character](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_ada.htm) mostly used in the symbols [`&optional`, `&rest`, `&key`, `&allow-other-keys`, `&aux`, `&whole`, `&body` and `&environment`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_lambda.htm).

Comment: Beautiful! I thought about lambda wrapping but settled on putting `funcall` before things. +1

Comment: Your option, `#!` behind the whole form, is clever too, and it won't depend on optimizing lambda forms (and `apply`), by automatically avoiding one call/indirection.

Comment: There's no problem with defining `&` as a function, though, and it's the same amount of typing: `(& my-function 1 3 2)`, and works with symbols too: `(&'list 1 2 3)`.  Same amount of typing without the overhead of apply, and without the complexity of a dispatch macro character.

Comment: You're right, and it can be `inline` and/or have a compiler macro.

Answer (score 4):

If you're inclined to black magic:

```
(defun black-magic (stream sub-char numarg)
  (declare (ignore sub-char numarg))
  `(funcall ,@(read stream)))

(set-dispatch-macro-character
  #\# #\! #'black-magic)
```

Rough example:

```
CL-USER> (defun foo (fn x y z)
           #!(fn x y z))
FOO
CL-USER> (foo #'* 1 2 3)
6
CL-USER> (foo #'+ 1 1 1)
3
```

(It's better to use `apply` however... but it's even better to keep things simple and use nothing of this sort.)

> Of couse we anyone can define something like that by reader macros, but i think it's not a very good idea to do such thing if you expecting than someone will read your code somtime.

Actually this sort of reader macro is syntactic sugar you're asking for. Do you reject your own idea now? Every time, when you use non-conventional syntactic sugar, you probably make things worse for your future code-readers.

Comment: This is a nice example of this kind of macro, although it doesn't actually save any typing as opposed to a one-character function name.  E.g., `#!(list 1 2 3)` is just no shorter than `(!'list 1 2 3)`, and similarly for `#!(f x y)` vs. `(! f x y)`.

Comment: @Joshua, to be honest, I don't see a reason to introduce this kind of syntactic sugar, I would always use longer and standard `(funcall f x y)`, I posted this option only as an example that this sort of things is possible.